# Insert CSS into html header via php Function

Tags: php, css, function, header

I have access to creating hooks to edit the appearance of websites, but no experience with php.
The hooks manpage gives examples such as:

```
survey_page_top()
{
    print '<div class="yellow">Special announcement text to display at the top of every survey.</div>';
}
```

Now, what I want to do is insert the following CSS into this function (the function is executed before rendering the page) so that instead of printing a message as above, it makes all print elements empty and prevents selecting and copying text. I found these CSS elements elsewhere that do that, but I don't know how they need to be put into the function to then be applied to the final page:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
body {
    
     visibility: hidden; display: none }
</style>
```

and

```
body, html{
     -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
     -ms-user-select: none;
     user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your php code, create a variable and then define the CSS style tag and css within the variable, there is no need to declare a function for this simple code, also the style tag goes within the head. Use the function along with the php variable if you need the function code as well.

```php
survey_page_top(){
  $cssStyle = '
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
        body {
            visibility: hidden; display: none
        }
        body, html{
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
    </style>';
  return $cssStyle;
}
```

HTML in your PHP file

```
<!--/ After the php that defines the variable /-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
<?=survey_page_top()?>

<!--/ Or  /-->

<?php echo survey_page_top(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks this might actually work too but the parsing system asks for functions (and they can be chosen to be employed in different places across the system), so it'r really probably best to have it all contained in the function, not define variables outside that might not be wanted elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it adding your code in PHP string, in this way:

```
survey_page_top() {
    echo '<style type="text/css" media="print">
    body {
        visibility: hidden; display: none
    }
    body, html{
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
    </style>';
}
```